# Tournures similaires à « and so on » et alternatives à « etc. »

Tags: anglais, usage, locutions, synonymes

Voici quelques exemples des adjectifs à partir de noms propres :

> Lagrange => Description lagrangienne.
>
> Newton => Mécanique newtonienne.
>
> Euler, Hamilton => eulérien et hamiltonien.
>
> Cauchy => Filtres co-cauchyssois
>
> etc.

Dans ce contexte, en anglais, on peut employer *and so on* ou bien *and so forth*.

La locution *et ainsi de suite* peut-elle employée de la même façon au lieu de etc. ?
Y a-t-il d'autres locutions courantes qui ont un sens voisin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je n'ai pas trouvé s'il existait un nom pour ce genre de locution consistant abréger une liste. On pourrait appeler cela une ellipse.

- `etc.` / `et caetera` est très bien. En rigueur de termes, vu son sens en latin (‘et le reste’), il faudrait le réserver aux ensembles finis.
- `et al.` ([article Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_al.)) a l'avantage de dire exactement ce qu'on veut (‘et d'autres’) et de fonctionner à la fois pour des gens (`et aliae`, `et alii`) et pour des trucs (`et alia`). Il est moins courant, mais vu la teneur de votre exemple, il sera probablement compris par vos lecteurs. En revanche, ce n'est toujours pas vraiment du français.
- `et ainsi de suite` marche bien aussi, mais si on veut ergoter, il n'y a pas de notion de suite (comme dans 1, 2, 4, 8, …) dans votre exemple.
- À l'oral, on emploiera volontiers `ou que sais-je` / `et que sais-je encore` et variantes, mais le registre est un peu soutenu. On ne l'emploiera surtout pas dans une publication scientifique (ne serait-ce qu'à cause du `je`).

A mon avis, le `etc.` reste le meilleur choix parce qu'il est très courant en français, et qu'il peut presque être pris dans son sens étymologique de ‘et le reste’ (parce qu'il n'existe pas une infinité d'adjectifs formés sur des noms de grands mathématiciens).

Comment: Quel est le problème si le reste est infini ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En français, on admet volontiers 'et cetera' pour compléter un ensemble infini (comme le fait par exemple le [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/et%20cetera)), mais [en latin](https://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=ceterus), `cetera` désigne ‘tout le reste’ (sous-entendu, d'un ensemble fini). Seul les esprits les plus tatillons y verraient une faute de français, je ne crois pas que c'en soit une.

Comment: J'ai du mal à concevoir que la grammaire latine empêche « tout le reste » de désigner un ensemble infini. Si c'est le cas, je voudrais bien savoir pourquoi.

Comment: En fait, c'est plutôt que le latin préférera `alia` à `cetera` si on ne sait pas si l'ensemble est fini, tout comme nous dirions 'd'autres' vs. 'les autres'. J'ai peur de sortir du sujet en développant davantage, mais pour résumer, je crois que cette nuance est latine et non française — donc ça va.

Answer (score 1):

Pour des personnes (comme c'est le cas ici), on peut aussi utiliser 'et consorts'.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu ; merci de votre réponse. C'est un mot courant ?

Comment: @dimitris Assez. Sauf que j'en y repensant je me rends compte que ça ne marche pas si bien ici. Il faudrait une liste de personnes, sans les adjectifs : "Lagrange, Newton, Euler, Hamilton, Cauchy et consorts".